# how to add a project level dependency in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an app and an android library in my application, in development env i would like to provide a project level dependency i.e. dependency in the 
(Project:XXX) build.gradle file.
This is how my project level build.gradle looks (partial view)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
// Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I get an error `Gradle DSL method not found : compile()`.

Is there a way in android to provide common project level dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add dependencies to any other scope except of `classpath` in the `buildscript` block.
Here's how you declare a project dependency (in another project, not in `buildscript`):

```
dependencies {
        compile project(':shared')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `dependencies` block inside the `buildscript`. It is wrong.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}



dependencies {
     compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
     compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'        
}
```